# I want to send an array of emails from a database table within the controller given a text input

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.4

This is the code from the blade view that pushes the array to the controller
The way it works is, a user types A or P for absent and late, i need to send an email if the input value for the present[] is A for each student but have failed to retrieve the student id from the inputs.

```
function addRow(data,index) {
        var table = document.getElementById('studentList');
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
        var id = document.createElement("label");

        id.innerHTML=data['id'];
        cell2.appendChild(id);
        var id = document.createElement("input");
        id.name="id[]";
        id.value=data['id'];
        id.type="hidden";
        cell2.appendChild(id);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var name = document.createElement("label");
        name.innerHTML=data['name'];
        cell3.appendChild(name);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);
        var attendance = document.createElement("input");
        attendance.type = "text";
        attendance.placeholder = "Class Attendance";
        attendance.name="present[]";
        attendance.size="5";
        cell4.appendChild(attendance);

    };
```

then my  controller is like this so far

```
 public function saveAttendance(Request $request)
{
    $student_id = $request->get('id');
    $class_id = $request->get('class_id');
    $term = $request->get('term');
    $teacher_id = $request->get('teacher_id');
    $status = $request->get('present');
    $isSendSMS = $request->get('isSendSMS');

    if ($isSendSMS == null)
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Attendance List Added Successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($status as $s)
            {
                $absent = ($s == "A");
                if($absent)
                     echo 'absent';
                else
                  echo 'other';
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: where do you have problem?

Comment: I want to return the student id here .... foreach ($status as $s)
            {
                $absent = ($s == "A");
                if($absent)
                     echo 'absent';
                else
                  echo 'other';
            }

Comment: what data do you get inside the `saveAttendance()` method. please add `$request->all()` result.

Comment: for example my json from the request->all() is {"class_id":"1","teacher_id":"1","term":"Choose Term","isSendSMS":"on","studentList_length":"10","id":["2","3","5"],"present":["A","A","L"]}, now i want to get every "id" where "present" is "A"

Comment: please add the result of `dd($request->all());` to know what data we are getting for processing

Comment: "id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "5"
  ]
  "present" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "A"
    1 => "A"
    2 => "L"
  ] i get this if after adding dd($request->all()); , so i need to return the "id" values for which present is "A" because i need the id to query the db

Comment: update foreach like `foreach ($status as $key => $s)` and you would be able to access the id using `$key`.

Comment: in the form also use `id` as the array key.

Comment: Thanks alot, i compared the keys and it worked